# getting python priority queue return item of largest priority

Tags: python, priority-queue

I am using Queue.Priority class in python 2.7 as below

```
q=Queue.PriorityQueue()
q.put((2,"second"))
q.put((1,"first"))
q.put((3,"third"))
print q.get(True)
print q.get(True)
print q.get(True)
```

This would return the following result since get() returns the item of lowest priority

```
(1, 'first')
(2, 'second')
(3, 'third')
```

Suppose,I need  get to return the item of highest priority .what should I do? Is there a way to do this other than overriding get() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just the first element of the tuple that matters, and it's an integer, you could simply negate it:

```
q=Queue.PriorityQueue()
q.put((-2,"second"))
q.put((-1,"first"))
q.put((-3,"third"))
print q.get(True)
print q.get(True)
print q.get(True)
```

This will print out:

```
(-3, 'third') 
(-2, 'second')
(-1, 'first')
```